# Problem with vertical alignment in some custom <li> and <span> tag

Tags: html, css, sass

I try to create an element similar to the "chip" element presents in the Angular Material library (https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview).

The element I want to build has a li tag that acts as a container, inside this element, I insert two span tags, one that contains the text and the other that contains the "x" that enable the user to delete the whole chip.

I have a small x (font-size: 10px) that is inline with text. 
I would like to make the x bigger (around 18px or 20 px), but when I try to enlarge it, I am no more able to align it with the text ( the text drop down )
Here is my code:

```css
.selection-choice {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 5px;
    background-color: rgb(102, 0, 204);
    color: white;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    font-size: 13px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: list-item;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


.selection-choice-remove {
    border: 1px white solid;
    margin: 4px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding: 2px 5px 0px 6px;
    height: 75%;
    color: white;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<li class="selection-choice" title="EXAMPLE">
 <span class="selection-choice-remove" role="presentation">×</span> 
 <span>EXAMPLE</span>
</li>
```

Thanks a lot to who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `display:flex` for the 'selection-choice' it will keep the x icon and the text are same line and middle in vertical.
About the x icon, I have removed the padding and margin; you just use **text-align:center** and **line-height** to make it in the middle

```css
 .selection-choice {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: rgb(102, 0, 204);
  color: white;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  font-size: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: list-item;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.selection-choice-remove {
  border: 1px white solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  color: white;      
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
}
.selection-choice .text{
 padding:5px 7px 
}
```

```html
<li class="selection-choice" title="EXAMPLE">
 <span class="selection-choice-remove" role="presentation">×</span> 
 <span class="text">EXAMPLE</span>
</li>
```

Maybe it useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I think this is the best solution for me because I get the desired result and I simplify the code without using any padding or margin. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `padding` to position the X, it's not going to scale properly if you change any sizings (whether that be the sizing of the font or the sizing of any parent/child elements). Try changing the last value (`padding-left`) depending on the size of the font you assign to the X. In this case, change `padding: 2px 5px 0px 6px` to `padding: 2px 5px 0px 4px`. You can also add a class to the text and give it `position: relative` and position it accordingly.

```css
.selection-choice {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 5px;
    background-color: rgb(102, 0, 204);
    color: white;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    font-size: 13px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: list-item;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.text {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
}

.selection-choice-remove {
    border: 1px white solid;
    margin: 4px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding: 2px 5px 0px 4px;
    height: 75%;
    color: white;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<li class="selection-choice" title="EXAMPLE">
 <span class="selection-choice-remove" role="presentation">×</span> 
 <span class="text">EXAMPLE</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer I didn't think about the position:relative property.

Answer (score 1):

now its `font-size` is equal to `18px`;

```css
.selection-choice {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 15px 5px 5px;
    background-color: rgb(102, 0, 204);
    color: white;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    font-size: 13px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: list-item;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


.selection-choice-remove {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px white solid;
    margin: 4px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding: 2px auto 0px ;
    color: white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
     line-height: 18px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<li class="selection-choice" title="EXAMPLE">
 <span class="selection-choice-remove" role="presentation">×</span> 
 <span>EXAMPLE</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for you contribution